# from dgl.data.chem import mol_to_bigraph, smiles_to_bigraph does not work

Tags: python, graph, import, dgl

I am working on graph classification problem based on molecules. My data is SMILES, and I want to convert it into graph and build model using DGL package.

I have installed the dgl package by using **pip install dgl** in spyder and **! pip install dgl** in google colab. I can import this package by using **import dgl**, but when I use **from dgl.data.chem import mol_to_bigraph, smiles_to_bigraph**, it gives me this error:

> **No module named 'dgl.data.chem'**

What is the problem here? Does anyone have experience fixing this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They moved them to branch library, DGL Life.

checkout this document.

https://lifesci.dgl.ai/api/utils.mols.html